# change color of bars in a concated chart(two bar chart) in altair

Tags: python, altair

i have two bar chart that vertically stacked.
i use blow code  for change color of them.

```
    alt.Color('variable', domain=['a','b','c'],range=['#for_a','#for_b','#for_c']
```

problem is, when i set color for one of them, other chart disappear or, when set color for both (when i set domain and range for both), color of one affect other bar. how solve that?

```
chart_a = alt.Chart(dfA).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('monthdate(date):O'),
    alt.Y('value'),
    alt.Color('variable',
             scale=alt.Scale(domain=['a','b'],
                            range=['green','yellow'])
             )


chart_b =alt.Chart(dfB).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('monthdate(date):O'),
    alt.Y('value'),
    alt.Color('variable',
              scale=alt.Scale(domain=['c','d','e','f'],
                             range=['#ffbb9e','#992e00','#9ecdff','#005799']),
             )
)
chart_a & chart_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altair shares scales between concatenated charts by default. To change this, you can use the tools covered in [Scale and Guide Resolution](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html).

In your case, it sounds like you want independent color scales:

```
(chart_a & chart_b).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```